# Python - esy-OSMfilter error when trying to work through the example - OSM_raw_data does not exist

Tags: python, windows, openstreetmap, osm.pbf

I am getting the following error when trying to go through the esy-osm [example](https://pypi.org/project/esy-osmfilter/):

```
INFO:esy.osmfilter.pre_filter:OSM_raw_data does not exist
```

I am using python 3.8 on Windows and the code I am using is below:

```
import os, sys
import configparser, contextlib
from esy.osmfilter import osm_colors as cc
from esy.osmfilter import run_filter
from esy.osmfilter import Node, Way, Relation

PBF_inputfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Geospatial_data\OSM_raw/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf')
JSON_outputfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Geospatial_data/OSM_filtered/liechtenstein.json')
prefilter = {Node: {}, Way: {"man_made":["pipeline",],}, Relation: {}}
whitefilter = []
blackfilter = []
[Data,_]=run_filter('noname',
                    PBF_inputfile,
                    JSON_outputfile,
                    prefilter,
                    whitefilter,
                    blackfilter,
                    NewPreFilterData=True,
                    CreateElements=False,
                    LoadElements=False,
                    verbose=True)

print(len(Data['Node']))
print(len(Data['Relation']))
print(len(Data['Way']))
```

Does anyone know where I am going wrong on this?

Answer (score 2):

you dont find the pbf file.

Please look at the path separator on you machine.
For windows, it’s ‘\’ and for unix it’s ‘/’.

You have used both simutaniously:
'Geospatial_data\OSM_raw/liechtenstein-latest.osm.pbf'

Cheers,
Adam

Comment: And please add    
 if __name__ == "__main__":
on the start of you script if you use Windows, so that you don't have to disable the multiprocessing, which will make esy-osmfilter run much faster